# How Can I Fix Firefox Breaking My Site With Content-Security-Policy Warnings?

Tags: firefox

The site works fine on Chrome/iOS/Safari/Android (you should be able to select and image and proceed to write a message on the next step). Firefox refuses to run my project's main script (you can't select an image or go forward), and gives the following error in the console:

```
> Content Security Policy: Directive ‘frame-src’ has been deprecated.
> Please use directive ‘child-src’ instead. (3) Unknown
```

It's very cryptic. I've tried the following:

**1)** Adding a meta tag for the CSP in the header.

Result: *Creates more errors if restrictive, same amount of errors if
   left to wildcards on all parameters.*

**2)** Locally serving all scripts.

Result: *I still get three unknown CSP errors. It also loads a lot
   slower since the dependencies are not being loaded from a CDN.*

**3)** Removing specific scripts.

Result: *It reduces the errors by up to one, but it seems all scripts
   are equally responsible. Very strange behavior.*

Is this a bug in Firefox that is unsolvable? I'm tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem to a small, reproducible example. (I just had a quick look, and your site works the same for me in Safari and Firefox on macOS. I can't tell from your description whether the results I'm seeing are what you call working or broken...)

Comment: It's broken for me on two different computers, windows 10 and Sierra on Firefox and Edge. It's very reproducible for me at least.

Do you see the same error in the console? That would help a lot if you did, because there might be some weird caching issue that would make a lot more sense than this.

Can you make a green checkbox by clicking image and proceed to the next page to write a message? The carousel swipes, but that's all.

Comment: Just as an experiment, what happens if you move your click handlers into the `$(document).ready(function() {...` section? I've a vague suspicion that they're not being added properly sometimes because the DOM isn't ready.

Comment: Oh dear, that was it. Thank you so much!

I was going down a very frustrating path. I refactored things to jQuery which solved some weird Type Errors in Firefox, but then when I resolved those I assumed that the remaining CSP error could break the script as that is what I read happened randomly. This made my code a mess, and I got sidetracked troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put listeners in $(document).ready as Firefox loads things differently as pointed out to me by Matt Gibson.

Content Security Policy did not cause the script to fail. However, it is a weird error message that gives you no information to where the error is originating, and can potentially break the site, but that is not what happened here.